# How to send dynamic arrays to copy_to_user in (Kernel Module)

Tags: c, pointers, ubuntu, kernel

I've been working hard on this but not getting any progress.

I am trying to send a the dynamic array from the kernel to the userspace. It seems that static arrays are easily sent to the userspace, but I get the filling that I am not doing something right for the dynamic array

the static or fixed variables such as int a, char b[100] works fine with the put_user or the copy_to_user. however when I try to pass the pointer the syscall is killed or has an error.

Is it possible to send an dynamic arrays using copy_to_user? 
I've been trying to solve this by myself for weeks but I am desperate for help and humbly ask for your guidance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In userspace,

```
memcpy(&data.items, ...)
```

doesn't work: this overwrites the storage of the `data_t.items` field, not the array it's pointing at. But this is exactly what your kernel code is trying to do.

Instead, you want to copy to the memory pointed to by `items`. This looks like

```
memcpy(data.items, ...)
```

in userspace and

```
void *user_items;
get_user(&user_items, &from->items);
copy_to_user(user_items, ...);
```

in the kernel, as you need to read the value of the field first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't understand the memcpy[data.items,...], where do we use it and assign it to?

Comment: @SunghoHong `copy_to_user(&from->items, ...)` is equivalent to `memcpy(&data.items, ...)`. I hope it's obvious to see why the second is wrong, and by analogy understand why the first is wrong.

Comment: No, there is no need to `kmalloc` any additional memory in the kernel. You already have an `items` array, you just need to copy it to the right place - you're copying it to the wrong place right now.

Comment: Okay I will give it a try. I am a bit confused because this worked when I assigned the array with fixed length.

Comment: @SunghoHong Yes, because a fixed-length array is represented *in-place* in the structure, but the variable-length array is somewhere *else* in the process's heap, you just have to follow a pointer to find it. The C code makes it look the same but it's not.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but what do I add to the second argument in the copy_to_user?  copy_to_user wants the 1) destination, 2) kernel data, 3) the size of the data.

Comment: I think you know the answer, but I don't have enough knowledge to comprehend what you are saying for the moment. sorry.

Comment: @SunghoHong The rest of `copy_to_user` is correct, the only part that's wrong is the destination address. Instead of `&from->items`, you need to use the *value* of `from->items`, which you can read using `get_user`.

Comment: I am switching to   item *items; and get_user(items, &from->items);  and copy_to_user(from->items, items, <size>)    <the get_user argument needed to be changed because it calls an error if you use &items